# How to allow class only inherit from one of two interfaces

Tags: c#-4.0

I have two interfaces `Interface1, Interface2`. I only want to `MyClass` inherits from one of them.

It should compile error if I define a class like this:

```cs
class MyClass : Interface1, Interface2 
{
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't, basically - sorry to give such a quick and negative response, but this just isn't something C# supports.

Comment: In the few instances I've come across something similar, unit-tests using reflection was the best way that was found. Nowadays there are also code analyzers that can be written, but since you've tagged your question C#-4.0, an old C# version, I guess you're using old tools as well. These are just alternatives, however, as @JonSkeet says, there is no way to get the compiler to prevent compiling such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not inheritance , it is implementation.

you should write one of them

```
class MyClass: Interface1
{
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question of "How do I make the code in the question fail to compile"

Comment: why not, it is clear to show you have to write one of them if you want just implement once, if not you can implement all of them

Comment: The OP wants to *prevent* a class from implementing more than one of them. You haven't said anything about how to perform that prevention (and indeed it's not possible).

Comment: Imagine if the question was "How do I prevent another class deriving from my one" - then the answer would be "use the sealed modifier" (with some other options as well). It wouldn't be "just don't derive from it".